# Columns missing when viewing db table in the field explorer

Tags: crystal-reports, sqldb

I am connecting a SQL database to a crystal report.  There is a specific column from a table that I need to pull data from.  When I go to the field explorer, the column does not appear. I checked to make sure it didn't have any funky properties and it is identical to some other fields that do appear in the field explorer.

So I am at a loss. If the column does not have any data will Crystal not display its name in the field explorer?

[image: Results Performing Organization Colum - Does not Display]
[image: SuperObjectID - Does Display]

Comment: You could try inserting some data into the column and see if it appears. I'm not familiar with empty columns being excluded, but data connections are often a little different system to system.

Comment: Also check settings on the db side, perhaps there's a discrepancy there.